# Returning right container type

Tags: c++

I'm trying to learn C++ properly. A problem I started thinking about is how to properly make a template function the right type of container. An example would be an implementation of merge sort. To avoid having to make a copy of a container when splitting it in half for the recursion step, I want to use iterators. This means that I need to have a merge function of the form:

```
template<typename ForwIt, typename Comparator>
... merge(ForwIt begina, ForwIt enda, ForwIt beginb, ForwIt endb, Comparator comp)
{
   Container foo;
   ...
   return foo;
}
```

My problems:

1. How do I define the function with the correct return type in an idiomatic way?
2. What should I replace the type "Container" with, so that it's an instance of the same container as the components to be merged? (I assume here that both parameters to merge are iterators for the same type of container)

In general, how to make the code as clean and efficient as possible?

Comment: @JT1: Note that almost no algorithm has anything whatsoever to do with containers.  I should be able to sort the 5th element through the 10th element of a 20 element vector, no problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Look at the standard [`std::merge`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/merge) :

```
template< class InputIt1, class InputIt2, class OutputIt >
OutputIt merge( InputIt1 first1, InputIt1 last1,
                InputIt2 first2, InputIt2 last2,
                OutputIt d_first );
```

The standard way to do this is to pass an (output) iterator, where your function will write the result. In the case of `std::merge`, it also returns an iterator to the element past the last element copied

Standard algorithms for containers take iterators as parameter, and when they return something, they return iterators. They never are "container aware".

Comment: Ah, that does it. I couldn't figure out how to take an iterator for storage without assuming anything about its size. Seems like std::back_inserter is the missing piece of the puzzle that makes this approach work.